# Macro to format strings inside notepad++

Tags: sql, macros, notepad++

I have a large list of data I want to convert into a different format without doing it manually.  I believe there should be a way of creating a macro of sorts to make this task far less time consuming in the long run!

My data looks like:

EquipmentHire = 99

EquipmentPurchase = 100

EquipmentSpec = 101

and so on.  I want it all converted to look like this instead: (so I can load it into a database)

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (99, ‘EquipmentHire’);

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done similar tasks in MS-Excel using string concatenation and string manipulation functions like substring(), charindex().

Basically, open your text file in Excel (assuming text will be in column A), set column B to be your string manipulation of column A, copy the formula down for all rows, and then copy the column B contents to a new text file.

If this is a one-off, that would be a faster approach for me than writing a macro.  I also did something like this via a powershell script a while back, but again, for a one-off Excel was faster for me.

**Added** --

Excel sample formula.  This is very, very format dependent.  If your data is always a consistent format (exact number of spaces around the equals sign, etc).  Perl, powershell, macro, etc etc will likely be a better approach if you need to do this often, or your format is going to vary by spaces, etc.

Assuming EquipmentHire = 99 is the contents of A1, the following would be in cell B1 to give you your SQL statement.

`="INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("&MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+2,1000)&", '" & MID(A1,1,FIND("=", A1)-2) & "');"`

Tested using sample data in original post and MS-Excel 2k10

Comment: Hi, Sounds interesting, thanks. :) Can you give me an example?  I'm not sure I understand "set column B to be your string manipulation of column A"

Comment: Working on an example now.  My remembering of Excel string functions is a bit slow...  I'll edit my post with an example shortly.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'm playing around with it myself at the moment.  Will save me alot of time and I'm learning in the process, win-win situation. :)

Comment: 2 columns, one has is ID (all 4 digit numbers) second column has a string for the corresponding ID.  Example: [A1] 0001 [B1] Equipment  But they vary: [B2] 0002 [C2] Purchase Order, [C1] 0003 [D1] View Consent Lists.  So they are not all the same length. Is there an easy way of modifying your formula to just grab all the contents on a cell?

Comment: I have this kinda working, but it wont let me reference cells not in C.  I am trying to result in: INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (a2 value here, c2 value here)      [a2 = 4 digit number] [c2 = string]     It works fine if both are set to c2, but that's not what I want. @OCary

Comment: To put the full contents of one cell into another cell, or use the full contents in the formula, or whatever, just reference the cell.  Say if you wanted to concatenate the string values for cells G1 and H1 into K1, then in K1 you'd enter the formula = G1 & K1

Comment: The contents of F2, F3,F4 & F5 are ALWAYS the same static string values.  However, A2 & C2, A3 & C3 etc.. are new rows of data.  I wrote the following formula ="UPDATE function_tst SET "&MID(F2,1,FIND("",F2)+40) &MID(A2,1,(A2)+40)&","&MID(F3,1,FIND("",F3)+40)&"'"&MID(C2,1,FIND("",C2)+40)&"',"&MID(F4,1,FIND("",F4)+40)&"'' "&MID(E2,1,FIND("",E2)+40)&MID(F5,1,FIND("",F5)+40)&MID(A2,1,(A2)+40)&";"      Which works fine, but if I copy the formula down the length of the spreadsheet, it automatically increases all the values by one.  This means it wont read the static string values stored in f2-f5.

Comment: Which gives this output: UPDATE function_tst SET function_id=1000,function_name='File Menu',function_desc='' WHERE function_id=1000;
"function_id" & "function_name" change as desired, but unfortunately, so do the cell references for the strings like "function_desc" Which I don't want to change.  I've given myself alot of work and have little to show for it.  Feel stupid!  Overcomplicated it I think! :\

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9738/discussion-between-ocary-and-grump)